# Issues With User Preference Window

Tags: interface, customization

Every time I exit out of the user preference menu it exits out of Blender completely. I changed it so I can view it in the main window. However in one of my files, the window is stuck there and it appears black and eventually crashes Blender. When I exit out of it, it exits out of Blender too. Anything I can do to get rid of it?

Blender 2.75a
NOTE: It was also doing this in 2.74 as well.

Comment: Would you upload your blend? Thanks to the way Blender works, the layouts of a particular project are saved with the file.

Comment: Looks like a bug. These are off topic on this site.

Comment: try resetting to factory defaults